# How to call python code from outside of Python

Tags: java, python

I am trying to call python method from my java file.

mypython.py

```
def ab():
  print "i am calling"
```

myjava.class

```
public void call()
{
   ab() // just want to call python method
}
```

I don't have any idea to do this.

When I search on google for this all info will say about jython. 
and I am not using jython. 
if it is possible to do without jython. 
or what is the best way to call my python code in java.

Comment: call Python in Java ? they're two different programming languages.

Comment: what is best way to request/response between these two languages?

Comment: Yes, you can use jython for this. So where is the real question?

Comment: What are you trying to accomplish?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use [Thrift](http://thrift.apache.org/tutorial/) for example. You'd write a Python server and use a Java client to access it. Here's an [example Java server & client](http://thrift.apache.org/tutorial/java/) and an [example Python server & client](http://tkang.blogspot.com/2010/07/thrift-server-client-in-python.html). There's also a consistent example on the [front page](http://thrift.apache.org/), which uses a C++ server and a Python client.

The basic idea is that you define the interfaces using the Thrift IDL, and it then generates language specific code for you. Thrift will deal with the remote procedure call for you.

Answer (score 0):

It is not possible to call `Python` method in `java` code. You can do it only with `C` or `C++`.